# How to structure a MySQL database for counties, cities, and states

Tags: mysql, google-maps, database-schema

I am re-designing a database for a lawyer that holds local alcohol laws.  The idea is that someone could look up their county or city and find out when the last or first time they could get a drink at a bar or buy alcohol at a store.  The problem I’m running into is that legal jurisdictions are ungodly complicated.  Problems include:

1. Cities that are independent (no county associated with them,
   Baltimore, MD for example)
2. One city name can span multiple jurisdictions (Falls Church, VA, for example, is an independent city and there is also a Falls Church, VA, that is part of Fairfax County)
3. Cities that CONTAIN counties (New York City, NY, for
   example, contains five different counties)

I wanted to employ this simple schema, but the situation is not so simple:

```
state {
  id (INT, PRIMARY KEY)
  name_short (CHAR(2))
  name_long (CHAR(14))
…}

county {
  id (INT, PRIMARY KEY)
  name (CHAR(30))
  state_id (INT, FOREIGN KEY, REQUIRED)
…}

locality {
  id (INT, PRIMARY KEY)
  name (CHAR(30))
  county_id (INT, FOREIGN KEY, CAN BE NULL)
  state_id (INT, FOREIGN KEY, REQUIRED)
...}    

hours {
  id (INT, PRIMARY KEY)
  locality_id (INT, FOREIGN KEY, CAN BE NULL)
  county_id (INT, FOREIGN KEY, CAN BE NULL)
  state_id (INT, FOREIGN KEY, REQUIRED)
  beer_and_wine_or_liquor (INT => 1=beer and wine only, 2=liquor only, 3=both)
  on_or_off_premises (INT => 1=on-premises only, 2=off-premises only, 3=both)
  start_time (INT => seconds after Sunday 12am)
  end_time (INT => seconds after Sunday 12am)
}
```

The idea was to query a city and return their local alcohol laws.   If a city deferred their laws to a county, there would be no entries in `hours` for that city at all, and then another query would be done on the county level.  This could cascade all the way up to the state level.  This way data redundancy is eliminated.   It may not even be necessary to have entries for every city in `locality` if they defer their laws to the county.

- Problem #1 is solved by allowing `county_id` in the `locality` table to
  be null.
- Problem #2 is solved by allowing multiple localities with
  the same name, but different county ids.
- **Problem #3 is still bugging
  me.  I have no idea how to solve it.  Can anyone help with this?  Or
  should I just chock NYC up to a special case?**

(Note that I am using this with Google Maps API to determine a person’s city and county (if it exists) based an address, intersection, or latitude/longitude.  Note also that zip searches are not an option because they span jurisdictions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take county_id out of the locality table and create a lookup table like so:

```
locality_counties {
    locality_id (INT)
    county_id (INT)
}
```

Then you can use it for either a 1:1 or 1:m relation between localities and counties. Your query could look something like this:

```
SELECT
    h.*,
    s.name_short AS state_abbr,
    s.name_long as state_name,
    l.name AS locality_name,
    c.name AS county_name,
    c2.name AS alternate_county_name
FROM
    hours h
JOIN
    states s
    ON h.state_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    counties c
    ON h.county_id = c.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    localities l
    ON h.locality_id = l.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    locality_counties lc
    ON l.id = lc.locality_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    counties c2
    ON lc.county_id = c2.id
```

You would get one record returned for each county. And each of those records would contain duplicate information for the initial county and locality, so you'd need to be good about stripping out the duplicates with code.

Comment: Thank you!  I think that should do the trick.  I am wondering, however, if state_id is necessary for the locality table.  The only reason I put it in was because of independent cities.  Similarly, I wish to reduce the amount of foreign keys used in the hours table, but since hours could apply to a locality, a county, or a state, I don't see how that is possible.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Personally, I'd leave state_id in the locality table just in case you ever needed to use that table for something that didn't involve the hours table. And I think you are correct about no way around the FKs in the hours table since they could apply to a locality, county or state. Your table is still pretty slim in the grand scheme of things!